# Create SQL view to show mark for each subject and total of marks for each student

Tags: sql, sql-view

I need to create a view from these 3 tables to show data like in this screenshot:

[image]

Create these 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    idStu int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(30)
)

CREATE TABLE Subjects
(
    idSub int PRIMARY KEY,
    subjName varchar(30)
)

CREATE TABLE Exam
(
    idStu int REFERENCES Student,
    idSub int REFERENCES Subjects,
    Mark float,
    CONSTRAINT idStu_idSub PRIMARY KEY(idStu, idSub)
)
```

Then I'm inserting some values:

```
INSERT INTO Student 
VALUES (1, 'Jacob'), (2, 'Amilee')

INSERT INTO Subjects 
VALUES (1, 'Mathematics'), (2, 'Science'), (3, 'English')

INSERT INTO Exam 
VALUES (1, 1, 10), (1, 2, 9), (1, 3, 8),
       (2, 1, 9), (2, 2, 10), (2, 3, 7)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation (aka `PIVOT`)

```sql
CREATE VIEW View_MyHomeworkThatICantBeBotheredToDo

AS

SELECT
    Student = stu.name,
    Mathematics = SUM(CASE WHEN sub.subjName = 'Mathematics' THEN e.Mark END),
    Science = SUM(CASE WHEN sub.subjName = 'Science' THEN e.Mark END),
    English = SUM(CASE WHEN sub.subjName = 'English' THEN e.Mark END),
    Total = SUM(e.Mark)
FROM Student stu
JOIN Exam e ON e.idStu = stu.idStu
JOIN Subjects sub ON sub.idSub = e.idSub
GROUP BY stu.idStu, stu.name;

GO
```

Comment: :-) love the view name :-)

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Please specify the DBMS for which this works.